# Github App authentication not showing login

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, github-api

I need to have a frontend that can interact with github repos, so i set up a Github App, then my node middleware calls the /authenticate endpoint

```
 const result = await axios.get(`https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize`, {
      params: {
        client_id,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3010/',
      },
    })
```

This is triggered as soon as a user on the frontend gets to a specific page.

The call itself returns OK 200, and i can see in the response data there's the html code for the Github authentication popup... but of course i cannot just inject it locally in the DOM, i would expect the popup to open automatically so the user can login and then receive the token and be redirected to the `redirect_uri`.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for the web flow](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#web-application-flow).

You should be navigating the user's browser to the end point (e.g. with a link). You shouldn't be requesting that page with axios (client-side *or* server-side).

After they have authorised it, they'll be redirected back to a URL hosted by your application. That URL will be passed an access token that your server side code can access the Github API using.

You might want to use [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) which takes care of most of this for you and has [a Github specific module](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-github2/).

Comment: Thanks this actually answers my question, i was looking at that documentation but the fact that it was supposed to be a link and not a server side call was completely lost to me, i still cannot find this clarification in the docs but maybe it's just something that is obvious when working with auth. Personally i'm at a loss every time i have a new auth flow to implement. Passport also seems like a good solution although i don't know if i want to rope in some new framework for such a small feature, good to know anyway!